# Verifying $\{e^{in\theta}\}$ is orthonormal in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Stated without proof in a text on Fourier Analysis:

> [image]

It is easy to see that

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta} \overline{e^{in\theta}} = 1
$$

since $|e^{in\theta}| = 1$. But how does one show that for $n \ne m$:

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta} \overline{e^{im\theta}} = 0
$$

Comment: That's not what you want to show. Drop that squared modulus. You want to show that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta}\overline{e^{i m \theta}}\, d\theta = 0$$ if $n\ne m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m\neq n$ then let $k=n-m\neq0$ and
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta} \overline{e^{im\theta}}d\theta 
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta} e^{-im\theta} d\theta \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n-m)\theta}d\theta \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ik\theta}d\theta \\
&= \dfrac{e^{ik\theta}}{ik}\Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
&= \dfrac{e^{ik\pi}-e^{-ik\pi}}{ik} \\
&= \dfrac{2}{k}\sin k\pi \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: On the 4th line I assume you're making use of the product rule?

Comment: The 5th line is substitution. But the 4th line is as well?

Comment: Yes -- that's the product rule, correct?

Comment: no integration $\int e^{ax}=\dfrac{e^{ax}}{a}$

Comment: I see. Studying that lemma will clear up my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is an integer $ \ne 0$ then

$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{int} dt= \frac{1}{i n}(e^{in \pi}-e^{-in \pi}) =0$,

since $e^{in \pi}=e^{-in \pi}= \cos( n \pi)=(-1)^n$.